# Trying to make a powerbi dynamic TOPN slicer to display the most repeated values

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to make a slicer that is able to manipulate a donut chart, that will display the most repeated values according to the number selected in the slicer.

Say I have this table

|  | Customer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Doug |
| 2 | Andy |
| 3 | Doug |
| 4 | Kathy |
| 5 | Andy |
| 6 | Doug |
| 7 | Doug |

I want to have a slicer that when on 1 will display Doug on the chart, on 2 will display Doug and Andy, and on 3 will display Doug, Andy, and Kathy.

I have a measurement

```
TopCustomer = Calculate(

TOPN(
'TOPN Selection'[Number of Customers'],
VALUES('Table'[Customers]),
RANKX( ALL ('Table'[Customers] ), COUNTROWS('Table'),,DESC)
)
)
```

In this case "TOPN Selection" is a table like this

| TOPN Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

And 'TOPN Selection'[Number of Customers] is a measurement

```
Number of Customers = SELECTEDVALUE(
'TOPN Selection'[TOPN Value]
)
```

I have my measurement "TopCustomer" set as the value in my donut chart, but when I use the slicer, nothing changes.

I am not sure if my measurements are off, or the way things are connected are off, or what may be the case as dax is a little new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test this code:

```
TopCustomer = 
VAR PickFromSlicer = SELECTEDVALUE('TOPN Selection'[TOPN Value])
RETURN
SUMX(
TOPN(
PickFromSlicer,
FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(
    VALUES(YourTable[Customer]),
    "Total",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(YourTable)),
    "Rank", RANKX(ALL(YourTable[Customer]),CALCULATE(COUNT(YourTable[Customer])))
    ),[Rank] <= PickFromSlicer),[Total],DESC),[Total]
    )
```

If we test it on a visual just you described at the end of your question:

Rank_1:

[image: 11111111]

Rank_2

[image: 22222222]

Rank_3

[image: 33333333]

I hope This solves your problem.

Comment: It works! When translated to a bigger scope, it appears that if you were to have customers that are repeated an equal amount of times, like say one more instance of "Andy" were added, then a TOPN Value selection of 1 would return both Andy and Doug, which I can just rename the slicer values to make it make sense. Just an interesting note. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Great to hear about your points. Good Luck!